# C# performance counter and nic name

Tags: c#, networking, performancecounter

The perfmon counter is using different NIC names compare to ipconfig/all and c# system call as you can see below (this is from ipconfig/all)

> ```
>    Ethernet adapter HHHH:       
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
>
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HP NC364T PCIe Quad Port Gigabit Server Adapter #3
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-29-0D-26-59
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 166.49.47.10(Preferred)
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
> ```

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

I get `HP NC364T PCIe Quad Port Gigabit Server Adapter #3`. Exactly the same as ipconfig.
**BUT** the perfmon is using `HP NC364T PCIe Quad Port Gigabit Server Adapter _3` (underscore instead of hash). Do I have to use a different call to get the same exact counter name as what the perfmon has? If so, what is it?

Comment: You get `"HP NC364T PCIe Quad Port Gigabit Server Adapter #3"` using WMI too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would use the registry to list the Network devices in a native way.
There are many different ways to retrieve information, but not all ways display
information like system does.
A possible code sample could look like this (not fully error handled).
It works for me on Windows Vista 32/64 bit and 7.
It's quite a bit different from the NET class, but it think it does the same way.
The Namespace "using Microsoft.Win32" must be added to run the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListPCIDevices(false, listBox1);
    }

    public static void ListPCIDevices(bool ListOnlyNetworkDevices, ListBox LB)
    {
        string NetKey = @"SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\PCI";
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(NetKey))
        {
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {

                    foreach (string skSubName in sk.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {

                        using (RegistryKey ssk = sk.OpenSubKey(skSubName))
                        {

                            object ItemName = ssk.GetValue("DeviceDesc");
                            object ItemCat = ssk.GetValue("Class");
                            if (ItemCat == null) { ItemCat = "Unknown"; }

                            if ((ItemName != null) && ((ItemCat.ToString() == "Net")||(!ListOnlyNetworkDevices)))
                            {
                                LB.Items.Add(ItemName.ToString().Split(';')[1]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```